# Intermittent error message with ROC metric for rfe in caret

Tags: r-caret, feature-selection

I am using rfe in caret to perform feature selection based on the ROC metric from twoClassSummary for a logistic regression model created from an imbalanced dataset (approx 25:1). More often than not I get an error message. Sometimes however I do not.

On the two occasions that the code has run without error (giving a believable result), I have run the exact same rfe line again immediately, and it has failed with this error message:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "undefined columns selected"
```

(Note that the task number can also vary up to 4.)

```
myLRFuncs <- lrFuncs
myLRFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary
rfe.ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = myLRFuncs,
                       method = "cv",
                       number = 5,
                       verbose = TRUE)
train.ctrl <- trainControl(method="none",
                           classProbs=TRUE,
                           summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                           verbose=TRUE)
glm_rfe_ROC <- rfe(x=train[,-c("outcome")],y=train$outcome,
                   sizes=c(1:5, 10, 15, 20, 25),
                   rfeControl=rfe.ctrl,
                   method="glm",
                   metric="ROC",
                   trControl=train.ctrl)
```

I am aware that I could use lasso or gradient boosted regression, and so avoid rfe, but I plan to use this approach for a wide range of additional algorithms, so would really like to have this working reliably.

Comment: Can you send the results of `sessionIfno()` and a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be related to how you are subsetting your predictors:

```
> train <- data.frame(outcome = 1:10, x1 = 1:10, x2 = 1:10)
> train[,-c("outcome")]
Error in -c("outcome") : invalid argument to unary operator
> train(x = train[,-c("outcome")], y = train$outcome)
Error in -c("outcome") : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Max